# Is chargeback possible with Paypal transactions, if no receipt of products/services?

Tags: paypal, receipt, chargeback

Someone sent me several hundred U.S. dollars Paypal for in exchange for services. This was a verbal agreement, and there was no receipt. I have decided **not** to fulfill my end of the agreement, but want to keep the money sent via PayPal anyway. Can the other party  chargeback the money sent to me via PayPal, i.e. take the money back?

Comment: The method used to send money was "Send money to friends and family"

Comment: Are you seriously asking on here if PayPal is going to let you get away with committing fraud?

Comment: Did you ship something? Then no. If not, then yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/security/chargeback-guide), if he or she used a credit or debit card, then yes.

Comment: And they should be able to if you are NOT fulfilling your end of the deal. Person experience with paypal they will often side with the buyer or sender of money.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you or the other person has a receipt, all transactions can be disputed up until 90 days. If the other person decides to create a dispute and escalate it, paypal will take matters into their own hands and create an investigation. Now, it is up to paypal to decide if you get to keep the funds or if it goes back to the other person.